# Can I install Linux with Windows with the following Partition setup?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

The following are my Hard disk partitions, Can I dual boot Linux with Windows after installing Linux in the unallocated space.

[image: partitions]

Comment: Sure you can, why do you think you should not be able to do so?

Comment: Since the disk is Basic MBR there are chances that you end up converting it into dynamic disk if you create more partitions. Try Easeus partition master to convert disk into GPT first before proceeding

Comment: I asked this because the unallocated space is a logical partition and not a primary one.